# Transferring a file from Server to Client reults in a very low download speed

Tags: java, performance, networking, download

I'm downloading a file of 45 MB from a Server using Sockets. Whilst measuring the traffic of my system shows me a download speed of around 4 MB/s, in Java, I only measure 60 KB/s.

Client-Sided:

```
int fileSize = Network.in.readInt(); //DataInputStream
byte[] data = new byte[fileSize];
for(int i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
{
    if(i % 1024 == 0)Log.info("Downloading: " + (i / 1024) + " KB / " + (fileSize / 1024) + " KB");
    data[i] = Network.in.readByte();
}
//int bytesRead = Network.in.read(data,0,data.length);
//int current = bytesRead;
//
//do {if(current % 16384 == 0)Log.info("Downloading: " + (current / 1024) + " KB / " + (fileSize / 1024) + " KB");
//     bytesRead = Network.in.read(data, current, (data.length-current));
//     if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
//} while(bytesRead > -1);
```

Server-Sided:

```
out.writeInt(data.length);   //DataOutputStream
//for(int i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
//{
//  out.writeByte(data[i]);
//}
out.write(data, 0, data.length);
```

Using the alternatives that are commented out makes no difference at all.

Comment: ... and *how* do you measure your speed?

Comment: By just printing the current number of received bytes in the loop.

Comment: My logging system prints the current time, therefore i can calculate how much was downloaded in one second. It also takes about 13-14 minutes to download 45 MB, so that also results in a download speed of around 60 kB/s.

Comment: @Geosearchef Logging is not free. Try to log not each kb but each 100 or total time without logging.

Comment: What type `Network.in` have?

Comment: i logged about every 20 KB and it stayed the same, Network.in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())

Comment: What did you get when you read blocks at a time?

Comment: Still the same problem when using readFully() or reading in blocks of 8192 Byte, about 60 KB/s, but during that time I'm unable to do anything else, it uses the whole bandwidth of 4 MB/s.

Comment: i fixed the problem, I apparently did not upload the new server software to the server whilst being 100 % confident that I did, so the server was sending byte by byte in a loop, now I'm using the code reading in 8KB blocks and sending by calling out.write(data, 0, data.length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a `byte[]` and reading it into a `byte[]` but only reading one byte at a time which means calling operating systems once for every byte in the file. I suggest reading a `byte[]` at a  time. e.g. use `readFully`

```
int fileSize = Network.in.readInt(); //DataInputStream
byte[] data = new byte[fileSize];
Network.in.readFully(data);
```

If you need to see it progressively you can do

```
for (int start = 0; start < fileSize; start += 8192) {
    Log.info("Downloading: " + (start / 1024) + " KB / " + (fileSize / 1024) + " KB");
    Network.in.readFully(data, start, Math.min(fileSize - start, 8192));
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem, about 60 KB/s, but during that time I'm unable to do anything else, it uses the whole bandwidth of 4 MB/s.

Comment: @Geosearchef that certainly makes no sense. What is your upload speed for your server's internet connection?

Comment: @Geosearchef what happens when you test this over loopback?

Comment: server upload speed is up to 1Gb/s, i fixed the problem, I apparently did not upload the new server software to the server whilst being 100 % confident that I did, so the server was sending byte by byte in a loop